# Nokogiri and Scraping a Betting website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css-selectors, nokogiri

I am attempting to scrape the ladbrokes website using Nokogiri.  I have no problem scraping the names, for example, of matches or events that are available to bet on.  This is my seeds file which populates my database with the events available.  I am using selector gadget to use the required CSS elements.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://sports.ladbrokes.com/ie-ie/class-c110000006"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css("td:nth-child(2)").each do |event|
sport = event.at_css(".eventLink").text

Event.create(:name => sport)
```

end

When I try to use this to scrape the time of the event or the odds available I am having no luck, however.  When I run 'rake db:seed' in the command line, I get an 'undefined method for nil:Nilclass' error.  I am just wondering why is it possible to access the text contents of one CSS element but not another.

Comment: Can you please share complete error stacktrace. This `'undefined method for nil:Nilclass' ` is insuffiecient to debug.

Comment: The reason why you're baffled is that you're ignoring the most important clues to the problem: the specifics in the error message.

Comment: @KirtiThorat this is the complete stack trace: